# How to make a proper error object?

Tags: python, error-handling, python-module

I'm working on making a small Python module. I want this module to return errors, if any occur. What is the proper or standard way to create error objects in Python?

**Edit:** I'm not really sure how to create my own errors, surely because i am not sure how errors work (i just know how to catch them in `try: ... except: ...`).
So right now i made draft error messages, errors are strings. When something goes unexpected i print the and `return None`. I guess that's not the proper way :)

*Example:*

```
    ...
    self.IsNotStringError = "Args was not a string."
    ...

def myMethod(self, args)
    """ Args must be a string. """
    if not isinstance(args, str):
       print IsNotStringError
       return None
    else:
        do things...
```

**Edit(bis):** On reading the answers below, i have looked further into Python documentation. There is [a tutorial on how to make user-defined exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions).

*Example from the documentation:*

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own exception class by inheriting `Exception`:

```
class YourError( Exception ): pass
```

next just raise it whenever you need to:

```
raise YourError("error message")
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why you `pass` after your exception, nor why the error message is not defined in the YourError class. Could you explain?

Comment: Nevermind, i found [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions)

Answer (score 2):

The question is always:

- returning some error object or
- raising an exception

It all depends on the individual usecase and what you are trying to accomplish.

An explicit exception is often the better choice. Creating your own exception by inheriting from Exception gives you full control. Passing arbitrary values to the constructor of your own exception is straight forward. Catching the exception on the caller side and introspecting the stored data of the exception is also trivial.

You have to be more specific if you expect more than a meta-answer.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really understand the difference between an error and an exception to start with. Could you give an example of how to construct an exception? Are there any standards for this?

Comment: I found [some documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions) on how to create custom Exceptions. But i am still not quite sure as to what difference there is between error and exception.